# When building Antlr, Visual Studio gives an error "cannot find the file specified" without naming the file

Tags: java, c#, parsing, antlr

I installed the antlr parser into my project, then tried to build.  The build failed with a message "The system cannot find the file specified" from the Antlr parsing project.  But it doesn't tell me what file is actually missing.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The file it could not find was the version of the JRE it wanted.  In my case, this was

```
c:\programfiles (x86)\java\jre1.8.0_31.
```

For future versions of antlr, the exact jre version will likely  change.